# Obtain the value of json file using dynamic variable value in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to retrieve the values ( username, password, url ) from json file using dynamic variable value in Node js file.

JSON file -> config.json

```
{
  "ro2" : { 
    "username": "testUser1",
    "password": "test",
    "url": "testUrl"
  },
  "sy2" : { 
    "username": "test1",
    "password": "test1",
    "url": "test1Url"
  }
}
```

Node js file

A function is defined which has datacentre( ro2, sy2 ) parameter passed value . If i hardcode, i am able to retrieve the exact value by using below
var username= config.ro2.username;
console.log(username) // Return testUser1 which i needed

but if i use dynamic value

var username= `config.${dataCenter}.username`;
console.log(username) // Return config.ro2.username which is incorrect

```
function (dataCenter) {
var config = require('./configuration/config.json');

var username= `config.${dataCenter}.username`;
var password= `config.${dataCenter}.password`;
console.log(username) \\ Return config.ro2.username which is incorrect, required testUser1 value
console.log(password) \\ 
}
```

How i get the value from json by using dynamic value passed dataCenter ( ro2, sh2)??

Comment: ok, so if I get it right, try this --> const username= `${config[dataCenter].username}`; ... and same goes for password

Comment: Aren't you looking for square brackets? Like  `var username=config[dataCenter].username`...

Comment: You're looking for Property Accessors I believe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: const username= ${config[dataCenter].username} worked for me! Thanks @DominikMatis